# Angular 2 - Set value of (html) select with model-driven

Tags: html, angular

I have the following select (PUG)

```
select.custom-select(name='category', formControlName='category')
    option(*ngFor="let category of essentials.categories") {{category.name}}
```

This code works but I would like to bind the form control to `category.code` such as:

```
select.custom-select(name='category', formControlName='category')
    option(*ngFor="let category of essentials.categories" [ngValue]="category.code") {{category.name}}
```

With the above code, I'm getting an error (`Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'option'`). I also tried with `[value]="category.code"` without success...

Edit: I'm using Angular 2 RC7

Comment: did you try sth like this `select.custom-select(name='category', formControlName='category',
    '*ngFor'="let category of essentials.categories",  '[ngValue]'="category.code") {{category.name}}`?
`

Comment: @mic4ael no but it doesn't seem right... the loop has to be in the option not the select (according to all the documentations).. I will give it a try though

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping `*ngFor` by enclosing it with quotes (remember about `[ngValue]` as well.

```
select.custom-select(name='category', formControlName='category')
       option("*ngFor"="let category of essentials.categories", "[ngValue]"="category.code") {{category.name}}
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! Can you explain why it has to be enclosed with quotes?

Comment: It is necessary because you are using some special charactes. https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2270